# back to login page firebaseUI after sign out?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-authentication, redirect

I just finish create sign out button using FirebaseUI, but if I click sign out button, I still on my page, not back to my login page. The idea is, if I click sign out button, user will sign out and back into login page. How I can make it ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.1.3/firebase.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>You Done</h1>
        <h3 id="myemail"></h3>
        <button type="button" id="btnout" class="btn btn-action hide">Sign out</button>
        <script>
            const btnout    = document.getElementById('btnout');
            const superemail      = document.getElementById('myemail');
            const config = {
                apiKey: "AIzaSyBIi34ndZxxLq2l1gtpzFnAjohPU18pyCk",
                authDomain: "skripsi-adeguntoro.firebaseapp.com",
                databaseURL: "https://skripsi-adeguntoro.firebaseio.com",
                projectId: "skripsi-adeguntoro",
                storageBucket: "skripsi-adeguntoro.appspot.com",
                messagingSenderId: "181721142188"
            };
            firebase.initializeApp(config);
            firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged (firebaseUser =>{
                if(firebaseUser){
                    btnout.classList.remove('hide');
                    console.log(firebaseUser);
                    superemail.innerHTML = firebaseUser.email;
                }else{
                    console.log('not login');
                    btnout.classList.add('hide');
                }
            });
            btnout.addEventListener('click', e => { 
                firebase.auth().signOut();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use

```
window.location = "http://my.url.here";
window.location.href = "http://my.url.here";
```

try this. it will help you